# Android audio recorder with tagging

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

Sometimes I find voice recordings to be the easiest way to make notes to myself (e.g. hearing/reading some new Arabic vocabulary, but not immediately writing it down or consulting the dictionary; some spontaneous moral philosophy question that I want to consider later, etc.).

To categorise them, I'm looking for an app with tagging for recordings - either as metadata or part of the filename, doesn't matter. Preferably it would be a good FOSS app, but in any case I also haven't found any proprietary app.